# How to cause an action at a specific time with Timer

Tags: java, timer

I am writing a program that uses a countdown timer. When the user clicks on the "New Game" button, the program will choose a random number between 1 and 1000 and the user must guess the correct price within 30 seconds. So I have the time working, but I'm unsure how to display how long it took the user to guess the correct answer if it is under 30 seconds.
Currently in my code I have (this is under the private class `Answerlistener` the rest of my code is at the bottom):

```
myTimer1.stop();
double timer = 30.0 - myTimer1.stop();
messageLabel.setText("Correct! It took you " + countTotal + " tries, in " + timer  + " seconds");
messageLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

But, I keep getting an error message with the double timer, so I know this is not right, but I'm not sure how to fix it. In addition, if the timer reaches `0` before the user has guessed the correct answer I want the message "you lose" to be displayed. Currently in my code I have (this is under the private class `Answerlistener`):

```
else if (sum > answer && myTimer1 == 0)
{
    messageLabel.setText("You Lose");
}
else if (sum < answer && myTimer1 == 0)
{
    messageLabel.setText("You Lose");
}
```

However I also get an error message again with `myTmer1 == 0` so I know this is not right, but I don't know how to fix it. So how can I have my program print "you Lose" if the user hasn't guessed the correct answer and the timer equals `0`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is all of my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ClockGame extends JFrame {

    //Declare fields for GUI components
    private JTextField guessField;
    private JButton newGameButton;
    private JLabel messageLabel;
    private JLabel guessLabel;
    private ImageIcon clockImage;
    private int countTotal;
    private Random rand;
    private JLabel title;
    private int number;
    private Timer myTimer1;
    public static final int ONE_SEC = 1000;   //time step in milliseconds
    public static final int TENTH_SEC = 100;
    private Font myClockFont;
    private JLabel timeLbl;
    private int clockTick;      //number of clock ticks; tick can be 1.0 s or 0.1 s
    private double clockTime;   //time in seconds
    private String clockTimeString;

    public ClockGame() {
        //Build GUI
        super ("Clock Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set layout
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Create the main panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        //Create components and place them in the panel
        rand = new Random();

        guessLabel = new JLabel("Guess: ");
        guessField = new JTextField(20);
        messageLabel = new JLabel("                             Click New Game to Begin");
        clockImage = new ImageIcon("clock.jpg");
        newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        title = new JLabel("The Clock Game", clockImage, SwingConstants.CENTER);

        clockTick = 300;        //initial clock setting in clock ticks
        clockTime = ((double)clockTick)/10.0;

        clockTimeString = new Double(clockTime).toString();
        myClockFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);

        timeLbl = new JLabel();
        timeLbl.setFont(myClockFont);
        timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);


        //Set font for clockGameLabel
        title.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 24));

        //Set messageLabel Color
        messageLabel.setOpaque(true);
        messageLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        newGameButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        guessField.addActionListener(new AnswerListener());

        //Add components to the panel
        mainPanel.add(guessLabel);
        mainPanel.add(guessField);
        mainPanel.add(newGameButton);
        this.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(messageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(timeLbl);


        //Add the panel to this JFrame
        this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Sizes this JFrame so that it is just big enough to hold the components
        this.setSize(340,225);

        //Make the JFrame visible on the screen
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class AnswerListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Code to check to see if answer is correct
            int sum = number;
            int answer = Integer.parseInt(guessField.getText());
            guessField.selectAll();
            Color purple = new Color(153, 153, 253);

            countTotal++;
            if (sum < answer)
            {
                messageLabel.setText("Too High");
                messageLabel.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else if (sum > answer)
            {
                messageLabel.setText("Too Low");
                messageLabel.setBackground(purple);
            }
            else if (sum > answer && myTimer1 == 0)
            {
                messageLabel.setText("You Lose");
            }
            else if (sum < answer && myTimer1 == 0)
            {
                messageLabel.setText("You Lose");
            }
            else
            {
                myTimer1.stop();
                double timer = 30.0 - myTimer1.stop();
                messageLabel.setText("Correct! It took you " + countTotal + " tries, in "
                 + timer  + " seconds");
                messageLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);            
            }
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            number = rand.nextInt(1001);
            messageLabel.setText("              The price is between $1 and $1000, begin.");
            messageLabel.setBackground(Color.green);
            countTotal = 0;
            clockTick = 300;
            clockTime = ((double)clockTick)/10.0;
            clockTimeString = new Double(clockTime).toString();
            timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);
            myTimer1 = new Timer(TENTH_SEC, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    clockTick--;
                    clockTime = ((double)clockTick)/10.0;
                    clockTimeString = new Double(clockTime).toString();
                    timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);
                    //System.out.println(clockTime);
                }
            });
            myTimer1.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClockGame frame = new ClockGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check if the timer has reached 0 within the action performed method of the Timers action listener. If the timer has reached 0 display message.